# How can I find the oracle package name in the Pro*C file?

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle-pro-c

Consider the package name as "ORA_DATAUPDATE" which is in oracle database.  There are a lot of Pro*C files (more than 100 files) in the UNIX environment. Maybe one or two Proc*C files uses this package  "ORA_DATAUPDATE".

Can anyone tell me  the unix script to find which Pro*C files contains the "ORA_DATAUPDATE" package name?

Comment: this question does not belong to SO, maybe to super-user...

Answer (score 1):

You can try grepping for it?

Or the other way is to for example rename the package to something different, and try to compile .pc's. The ones failing are the files in question...

Comment: @Rajesh Kumar G: then yes, i haven't found the way to do it short of grepping... But i observe the answers, probably there is one, so i'm interested in it too:)

Comment: Given that the ORA_DATAUPDATE string has to be passed to the database, the text may be preserved in the C executables. The other option is to drop the package (or the grants), run the code and see if it falls over.

Comment: @Gary: As far as i remember, it's in the string literal, so could be extracted with `strings` utility from object files. This approach is a little bit more reliable than grepping the sources, i think.

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the solution.here is the unix command to find the search sting in the Pro*c files

```
       find . -type f | xargs grep "ORA_DATAUPDATE"
```